# Check if a set of objects intersect another set of objects

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

I have an object(LineA) that is composed of 4 children and sub-children. They are Meshes(MeshLineMaterial) and ArrowHelpers. Then I have another set of objects(Other Lines) of the same kind.
Sample object:

```
castShadow: false 
children: Array(2)
0: ja {uuid: "B883597B-392D-41EB-A306-33A2F065A5B1", name: "PathA", type: "Mesh", parent: Hc, children: Array(0), …} 1: tb {uuid: "8B507A56-437C-47C5-9A0A-43DE9D8DE0D4", name: "", type: "Object3D", parent: Hc, children: Array(2), …}
 length: 2 
__proto__: Array(0) 
 frustumCulled: true 
layers: Pf {mask: 1} 
matrix: U {elements: Array(16)}
 matrixAutoUpdate: true 
matrixWorld: U {elements: Array(16)}
 matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false 
nObjType: "Path"
 name: "Path"
 parent: wd {uuid: "20293B1F-868F-4A06-9A24-AF14738955A8", name: "", type: "Scene", parent: null, children: Array(121), …}
 position: n {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0} quaternion: ua {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, 
_onChangeCallback: ƒ} 
receiveShadow: false 
renderOrder: 0 rotation: Qb {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, 
_order: "XYZ", 
_onChangeCallback: ƒ} 
scale: n {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1} 
selectable: true 
type: "Group" 
up: n {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
 userData: {} 
uuid: "CC27818D-5EEE-4A89-A39C-7F56C8C8F9BB" 
visible: true 
eulerOrder: (...) 
id: 561 
modelViewMatrix: U {elements: Array(16)} normalMatrix: Y {elements: Array(9)} 
useQuaternion: (...)
 __proto__: B
```

I am trying to create a system where when I create LineA, it shouldn't collide/cross with Other Lines.

I have tried the bounding box and raycaster:

```
function collision()
{
  var originPoint = LineA.position.clone();
var bb=new THREE.BoxHelper(LineA, 0x00ff00);
bb.geometry.computeBoundingBox(); 
var collidableMeshList = OtherLines;
    
    for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < bb.geometry.attributes.position.array.length; vertexIndex++)
    {   
            
        var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( bb.position, bb.geometry.attributes.position.array[vertexIndex] );
        var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );
        if ( collisionResults.length > 0)  
        {
      console.log("true");
      hit = true;
     }
  } 
}
```

I tried referring to this [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GHofz?editors=0010)

```
function detectCollisionCubes(bb, Line2bb){
  bb.geometry.computeBoundingBox(); //not needed if its already calculated
  Line2bb.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  bb.updateMatrixWorld();
  Line2bb.updateMatrixWorld();
  
  var box1 = bb.geometry.boundingBox.clone();
  box1.applyMatrix4(bb.matrixWorld);

  var box2 = Line2bb.geometry.boundingBox.clone();
  box2.applyMatrix4(Line2bb.matrixWorld);

  return box1.intersectsBox(box2);
}
```

None of them seems to be working in my case.
They show no error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your setup but if `Line2bb` and `bb` have children, you can't just use the bounding box from their geometry properties. You also have to honor the extends of their children. The computation of such a bounding box can be done via `Box3.setFromObject()`. So `var box1 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( Line2bb );`. Consider to create `box1` only once outside of `detectCollisionCubes()` and then reuse the object instance.

Comment: @Mugen87
bb is box helper of the object. so it doesn't have a child. I have updated my question to state the kind of object I am dealing with. I created `var bb = new THREE.BoxHelper(VisualGroup)`. I also tried using the box as you said but in that case, also it doesn't work. It returns true always.

Comment: Hi @Sakaggi could you figure out any solution with the Raycaster and bounding boxes example? It's very interesting because it didn't work for me either.